# SecureField not calling onSubmit when Password system popover is presented

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, securefield

The onSubmit is not called on Enter if the passwords system popover is presented

```
SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    .textContentType(.password)
    .textFieldStyle(FTextFieldStyle())
    .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
    .onSubmit {
        if canLogin() {
            login()
        } else {
            focusedField = .username
        }
    }
```

[image]

Once the Passwords dialog is gone, the onSubmit works again on enter

How to get it always working

Comment: I think that is expected behavior, the first to dismiss the box and then to actually submit. I don't see what needs to be fixed.

Comment: its not expected, since you can still type into the field, so pressing Enter clearly represents the intent